# SAS: How to create a macro to re run a program while changing variable values

Tags: sas

I have a task to write a macro to "re-run your programs" using different values for a variable to reduce the mean of that variable in order to reduce a second variable dependant on the first below a certain threshhold. However, im new to SAS and from what ive read on macros i didnt see anything that obviously fit this description.

Comment: Please read the tag description.

Comment: This is a simulation. If you're looking for an optimization, you can also look into the SAS/OR procedures.

Answer (score 0):

This prove to be quite interesting question. I haven't found any pre-built methods for this, but maybe something like this maybe:

First I define the *norm*, eg. the distance from what you want.

```
%macro do_calc(value);
    %let res=%eval(&value.-1);
%mend;
```

You should locate the iteration direction at this point. Most likely just derive your function and nudge the numbers down the dimension. Something like

```
%macro update_vars (var1, var2);
     %let var1=&var1. + 0.1; 
     %let var2=&var2. - 0.2;
%mend;
```

The actual iteration is quite easy.

```
%macro iterate; 
    %let res=110;
    %let i=1;
    %do %while(&res.>100 or i>1000);
        %do_calc(&res.); /*Add var1, var2); here */
        %update_vars(&var1.,&var2.);
        %put &res.;

        %let i= %eval(&i.+1); /*failsafe*/
    %end;
%mend;
%iterate;
```